# CSS, Transparent background of a text

Tags: html, css, background

new to HTML and CSS, tried to look for answer but can't seem to find it. Unto the question.

The first code is my style.css the second code is for index.html

```css
h1 {
  background-image: url('linkto/images/transparent.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-family: "Amarillo";
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="homeSection" class="sect sectOne"></div>
<h1>Title of Web</h1>
<section class="parallax">
  <div id="servicesSection" class="parallax-inner"></div>
</section>
```

Now, If I had linked a a JPEG filed (instead of PNG), the H1 ("Title of Web") would show as red and the background is the JPEG file, however, I try to put a 50px by 50px transparent image (PNG) it doesn't work and the background just becomes white (default background, my guess).

So I want the text to be red (or whatever color) but the background of it being transparent, am I on the right track or am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: unclear what are you asking?can you more specific?

Comment: just don't make an image a background of your h1 https://jsfiddle.net/oux7gnfo/

Comment: @dreamhunter I want h1 to be coloured while the background of that heading to be transparent and see what is behind it.

Comment: @classicalConditioning if I don't add the transparent.png as a background it is still the same thing, the background of h1 is white.

Comment: please provide jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have tried

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal hey, here is the link for the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/_kznl/j8qk6c59/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use color to transperant to bg , RGBA color values are an extension of RGB color values with an alpha channel - which specifies the opacity for a color.

An RGBA color value is specified with: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha). The alpha parameter is a number between 0.0 (fully transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque).
like you need black transperant background

```
h1 {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
   color: red;
   font-family: "Amarillo";
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

search the rgb colors and set opacity what ever you need to the last value

Comment: I have tried this but to no avail, I added a class ID for the h1 and added 

`.titleofweb{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}`

but did you mean that I also make the background of the webpage transparent as well?

Comment: can you show your code in fiddle, i think there is a display problem in your css

Comment: Hey thanks, here is the jfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/_kznl/j8qk6c59/)

Comment: @kznl buddy i have change my code. is this what you need

Answer (score 2):

A transparent background means it will ***blend*** with the background of its container (which I assume in your case is the `<body>` tag). The default background of the web page is white, so the heading is going to appear on a white background, unless you change the background of the entire web page

Comment: That makes sense, so how should I go about this?

I mean I want the text to be above multiple different background images (parallax effect), that's why I'd like it to have a transparent background so that it seamlessly blends with two different backgrounds.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by multiple background images. If you set the background twice on an element, the one set after is going to override the one that was set before. If you want text over an image, you could wrap the h1 in a div, then set the background of the div to the image you want to use.

Comment: Well I kinda want the text (h1) to be like floating on top of the two divs.

`<div id="homeSection" class="sect sectOne"></div>
<h1>Title of Web</h1>
<section class="parallax">
<div id="servicesSection" class="parallax-inner"></div>
</section>
<div id="gallerySection" class="sect sectTwo"></div>
<div id="contactSection" class="subSection"></div>`

So I kinda want the text floating on top of sectOne and parallax-inner. Thus needed transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

The `<h1>` tag **should not have any background by default**. If you see a white background despite of changes, there's something else adding it.

Regardless, you can **try to use** `background: none` in your CSS

**Edit: Snippet updated based on what you provided. Now works as far as can see, still needs more work on your end.**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Amarillo";
  src: url('http://kesnielgalvan.atspace.cc/fonts/Amarillo.ttf');
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(232, 235, 255, 0.09);
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Amarillo";
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.h1alt {
  background-image: url("http://kesnielgalvan.atspace.cc/images/photo1.jpg");
}
.link {
  transition: 0.8s;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.link:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #EEA200;
  padding: 24px 10px;
}
.sect {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.subSection {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(103, 141, 172);
}
.parallax {
  background: url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/webtreats/assets/posts/973/full/tileable-dark-wood-textures-5.jpg") repeat fixed 100%;
}
.parallax-inner {
  padding-top: 12%;
  padding-bottom: 12%;
}
.sectOne {
  background-image: url("http://kesnielgalvan.atspace.cc/images/photo1.jpg");
}
.sectTwo {
  background-image: url("http://kesnielgalvan.atspace.cc/images/photo2.jpg");
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Kesniel Galvan</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <a class="link" id="home" href="#homeSection">About</a>
    <a class="link" id="services" href="#servicesSection">Services</a>
    <a class="link" id="gallery" href="#gallerySection">Gallery</a>
    <a class="link" id="contact" href="#contactSection">Contact</a>
  </nav>

  <div id="homeSection" class="sect sectOne"></div>
  <h1 class="h1alt">Kesniel Galvan</h1>
  <section class="parallax">
    <div id="servicesSection" class="parallax-inner"></div>
  </section>
  <div id="gallerySection" class="sect sectTwo"></div>
  <div id="contactSection" class="subSection"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out, but to no avail.
Here is the jsfiddle link for you to look at !
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/_kznl/j8qk6c59/)

Comment: The `<h1>` is not the problem, it does not have any background. The issue is this: **The Background image for the element above it does not extend to it**. This means that the white color behind the text is the background for the `<body>` . There are two ways to solve this, either set the background of the <body> to match the section (not recommended) or create a subclass for the <h1> and change the background for that one. 

I edited my answer to reflect the update.